# Issues creating boot and shutdown systemd daemon

Tags: shell, systemd, services, shutdown, units

I'm trying to create a config file for my unit but when I start the daemon after enabling and shutdown the computer it doesnt works. The script only executes the ExecStart line after network.target on boot.
Edit:
Code:

```
[Unit]
Description="Service that executes Discord Bot at Boot and Shutdown."
After=network.target
Before=poweroff.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mi_script_bash.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mi_script_bash.sh stop
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
[Install]
WantedBy= default.target poweroff.target
```

The ExecStart and ExecStop Calls are for the bash script mi_script_bash.sh (simple string comparison for calling to a NodeJs script):

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" == "start" ] && node /home/ser356/Escritorio/discordjs/app.js start

[ "$1" == "stop" ] && node /home/ser356/Escritorio/discordjs/app.js stop
```

And then the node script:

```
const {Client,Intents} = require("discord.js");
require('dotenv').config();
var hora=new Date();
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] }); 
var argumentos=process.argv[2];
console.log(argumentos)
//client.login("OTUwNTQyNDQ5MzYzODA4MzA2.YiabpA.bulmNmwGgz9s8kOPyvjngR_rSbo");



client.on('ready', () => {
var canal =  client.channels.cache.get("950644612517724171")
if(argumentos==='start'){
canal.send("Mi dueño me ha arrancado "+hora);
}

else if(argumentos==='stop'){
canal.send("Mi dueño me requiere "+hora);
}

else{
canal.send("nada")

}
});




 client.login('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally reached a solution working for me.

Dividing the Unit in two daemons and giving chmod 0644 permissions for each one

servicio_discord.service :

```
[Unit]
Description="Service that executes Discord Bot at Boot."
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mi_script_bash.sh start
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where the service IS executed `After` the Network service, `WantedBy=multi-user.target` indicates the services to run on multi-user state `Type=simple` indicates the daemon to run on the foreground

Equally:

servicio_discord_end.service

```
[Unit]
Description="Run Discord Bot at shutdown"
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mi_script_bash.sh stop
[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
```

In this case DefaultDependencies is no because we have Before option but not an after option as it would be expected by default.

See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7113#issuecomment-337451441

Then running:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable sistema*
systemctl start sistema*
systemctl status sistema* #optional
reboot
```